# FatalExecutionEngineError or InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, button, gsm

I have a piece of code that reads message from a phone connected to my computer.
the code is the one i copied under, it gives me always this two errors
sometimes it says:

> Unable to cast an object of type 'GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmPhone' to type 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke'. (System.invlaid.Exception)

thanks for help

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

    string storage = GetMessageStorageReading();

    try
    {
        DecodedShortMessage[] messages = CommSetting.comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, storage);

        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
            OutputReading(string.Format("Statut du message = {0}, Emplacement = {1}/{2}",
            StatusToString(message.Status), message.Storage, message.Index));
            ShowMessageReading(message.Data);
            OutputReading("");
        }

        OutputReading(string.Format("{0,9} message(s) lu(s).", messages.Length.ToString()));
        OutputReading("");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowException(ex);
    }

    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
}
```

Comment: What line shows the error?

Comment: as you know this two errors doesn't show any line, it gives me a new Tab whitch doen't contain any informations

Comment: So why have you posted the code if it is irrelevant? I am saying, at which point in the code above causes the error you have described (the '`System.invlaid.Exception`')? If this code is not the code that cause the error please post the code that does...

Comment: it is the code that cause problem, but it doesn't shows where the error is. if you have already seen this errors in some of you code you'll understand what I am saying.

Comment: the Tab's name is no source available

Comment: That does not look like a .NET exception type. It seems that this is being thrown from a library that you are using...